# Double COUNT, SELECT, LEFT JOIN with WHERE?

Tags: mysql

How to do this query right? All is ok except news table. It returns only first row.

```
 SELECT 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news WHERE news.author = '$user_name') as newscount,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM torrents WHERE torrents.user = '$user_name') as torrcount,
   users.date as userdate, 
   users.rep as userrep, 
   torrents.title as tortitle, 
   torrents.torrent as torlink, 
   news.link as newslink, 
   news.title as newstitle 
 FROM 
   users,
   torrents, 
   news 
 WHERE 
   (users.name AND torrents.user AND news.author) = '$user_name' LIMIT 0,30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing query does not specify how the 3 tables `JOIN` and the syntax you have used in the where clause is incorrect.

The `FROM clause` and `WHERE clause` could look something like this:

```
FROM users
INNER JOIN torrents ON users.name = torrents.user
INNER JOIN news ON users.name= news.author
WHERE users.name = '$user_name'
```

Because we have joined the 3 tables we only need to filter the users table, and the other tables will also be limited to the same user name.

BUT the trouble with using INNER JOIN's is that there MUST be joining records in both tables for each join. If your application logic allows a user with news but no torrent, or torrents with no news or a user without either torrent or news, then we can't use `INNER JOIN` so we use an `OUTER JOIN` instead.

`OUTER JOIN`s allow a record in one table but no matching record in the other

So: I would say your `FROM clause` will need to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s for both torrents and news

```
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN torrents ON users.name = torrents.user
LEFT OUTER JOIN news ON users.name= news.author
WHERE users.name = '$user_name'
```

If unfamiliar with joins I suggest [this visual guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Your overall query I believe would look like this:

```
SELECT (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM news
        WHERE news.author = '$user_name'
        ) AS newscount
    , (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM torrents
        WHERE torrents.user = '$user_name'
        ) AS torrcount
    , users.DATE AS userdate
    , users.rep AS userrep
    , torrents.title AS tortitle
    , torrents.torrent AS torlink
    , news.link AS newslink
    , news.title AS newstitle
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN torrents ON users.name = torrents.user
LEFT OUTER JOIN news ON users.name= news.author
WHERE users.name = '$user_name'
LIMIT 0, 30
;
```

---

**A suggestion**

An effect of joins is the you get a multiplication of the rows from the tables involved.

Here is something that *might* work for you instead

```
set @ncount := (
        SELECT COUNT(*) c
        FROM news
        WHERE news.author = '$user_name'
        )

set @tcount :=    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) c
        FROM torrents
        WHERE torrents.user = '$user_name'
        )     

SELECT
      @ncount newscount
    , @tcount torrcount
    , users.DATE AS userdate
    , users.rep AS userrep
    , torrents.title         AS Item_Title
    , torrents.torrent       AS Item_link
    , 'torrent'              AS Item_Type
FROM users
INNER JOIN torrents ON users.name = torrents.user
WHERE users.name = '$user_name'

UNION ALL

SELECT
      @ncount newscount
    , @tcount torrcount
    , users.DATE AS userdate
    , users.rep AS userrep
    , news.link              AS Item_Title
    , news.title             AS Item_link
    , 'news'                 AS Item_Type
FROM users
INNER JOIN news ON users.name= news.author
WHERE users.name = '$user_name'
LIMIT 0, 30
;
```

Comment: The problem is that in each case I get the same row in the second joined table http://i.imgur.com/hmPcJAI.png

Comment: for each row of one table, you will get all the rows of the other tables. There is 1 record for user table, 46 for torrent table and 83 for new (1*46*83 = 3818) rows in total. Yes there will be "repetition" that is how SQL works

Comment: take a look at this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1d3a/2 we select one user (A) which links to 3 Torrents and links to 2 News. 1*3*2 = 6 rows, **& every row is unique** but there is some repetition (see colmn news.title)

Comment: ok. so it's impossible to get all of this rows in one query, isn't it?

Comment: NO, all the rows are retuned by that one query. Perhaps they are just are not what you were hoping would happen. If that is true then you need to reconsider how you describe what it is you actually want. I will make a "suggestion" by adding to my answer.